# How do I get unique elements in my multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 1
                [value] => new
                [label] => New
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 3
                [value] => pending_payment
                [label] => Pending Payment
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 4
                [value] => pending_paypal
                [label] => Pending Paypal
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 5
                [value] => processing
                [label] => Processing
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 6
                [value] => complete
                [label] => Complete
            )
        [5] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 7
                [value] => canceled
                [label] => Canceled
            )
        [6] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 8
                [value] => closed
                [label] => Closed
            )
        [7] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 9
                [value] => holded
                [label] => Holded
            )
        [8] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 10
                [value] => payment_review
                [label] => Payment Review
            )
        [9] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 11
                [value] => new
                [label] => New
            )
        [10] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 13
                [value] => pending_payment
                [label] => Pending Payment
            )
```

**UPDATE** This is the result of the **print_r**.
As you can see the **array[0]** with **array[6]** are the same. Also the array[7] with the array[1]. How can I get rid of one of them ? thx

I tried smth like this:

```
$input = $my_array
$temp  = $input;

foreach ( $temp as &$data ) {
    unset($data['id']);
}

$output = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique($temp));
```

but with no any result :( .

Comment: seems a mission to `array_column` and `array_unique` :) Can you change your output code in your question to a `echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);` one, please?

Comment: srry I don't get it . Can u explain me , with more details ? thx

Comment: I will try to simulate your problem and give you a solution based on the functions I've mentioned.

Comment: I did the print_r  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();

foreach ($myArray as $array) {
    if (isset($result[$array['value']])) {
        continue;
    }
    $result[$array['value']] = $array;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Attila this should help.
Your `$my_array` is renamed in this example into `$wholeArray`. And I thought it woulf be enough to compare the labels:

```
$index=0;
$length = count($wholeArray);
foreach($wholeArray as $arrayElement){
    $temp = $arrayElement['label'];
    $index++;
    for($i = $index; $i < $length; $i++){
        if($wholeArray[$i]['label'] == $temp){
            unset($wholeArray[$i]);
            $length --;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any questions to the code feel free to ask :)